# yii2 related model not found during validation in junction table

Tags: validation, yii2, junction-table

I have a junction table `Znw` with 2 ids (`a_id` & `wz_id`), and a form with 2 select boxes according. I would like to check in the rules, if `fieldn` of the corresponding model `a` have the same value as `field` of the corresponding model `wz`.

Rules:

```
[['a_id', 'wz_id'], 'compareFields', 'on' => 'createwz', 'params' => []],
```

custom validation function (now only to check if the correct value is found):

```
public function compareFields($attribute, $params) {
    $this->addError($attribute, $this->a->fieldn);
    return false;
}
```

relation `a`:

```
public function getA() {
    return $this->hasOne(\app\models\A::className(), ['id' => 'a_id']);
}
```

this relation is otherwise working well in views etc.

relation `wz`:

```
public function getWz() {
    return $this->hasOne(\app\models\Wz::className(), ['id' => 'wz_id']);
;}
```

controller:

```
public function actionCreatewz() {
    $model = new Znw;
    $a = A::find()->where(['id' => $_GET['Znw']['a_id']])->one();

    $model->scenario = 'createwz';

    try {
        if ($model->load($_POST) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(Url::previous());
        } elseif (!\Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $model->load($_GET);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $msg = (isset($e->errorInfo[2])) ? $e->errorInfo[2] : $e->getMessage();
        $model->addError('_exception', $msg);
    }
    return $this->render('createwz', [
                'model' => $model,
                'a' => $a,
    ]);
}
```

if I'm adding `$this->wz->field` to the custom validation function, it shows the right value. If I'm adding `$this->a->fieldn`, then I'm getting the following error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

however, in the $_POST request both ids (`a_id` & `wz_id`) are there with the right value, so I should be able to see corresponding `a` model attribute. Why am I getting this error instead? Can you please point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show us more code of controller?

Comment: From the view of your code and the error message, I guess that the attribute `a_id` of `$model` doesn't be assigned properly. It might be the results that you didn't make `a_id` safe in the scenario of `createwz`. You could verify this by `\Yii::warning($this->a_id)` in `compareFields`.

Comment: you mean like `$this->addError($attribute, \Yii::warning($this->a_id));` ? is empty.

Comment: Does `$model->a_id` has value before validate?

Comment: at least in the `$_POST` request it has a value, and after that in the `$model->load($_POST)` it's assigned correctly, so after that I see in `print_r($model)`: [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
        (
            [a_id] => 34782
            [wz_id] => 827
        )

Comment: but there is a strange thing also (maybe only for me): `[_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
        (
            [a] => 
        )` it's empty. Is it a problem? Strangely I don't see such `related` for `wz`...

Comment: That means there is no record being found in model `A` with id equals 34782.

Comment: There is definitely a record with this id in `A`, because on the form the select shows already what in Table `a` can be found.

Comment: `$this->addError($attribute, \Yii::warning($this->a_id));` is not working. also not with `wz_id`

Comment: Just `\Yii::warning($this->a_id);` as a statement, then open the log file seeing what within.

Comment: you should show more code for the model  where you are running the validation and have declared the relations there must be something wrong there.

Comment: I have no clue what else could I show that could be relevant. There is not really much more.